# Java is 'unable to find valid certification', although TrustStore contains root certificate

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception, truststore, root-certificate

I'm trying to send an HttpRequest to "https://api.ecs.echa.europa.eu" using

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://api.ecs.echa.europa.eu"))
                .GET()
                .build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1).build();
HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Executing this code I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Now I already found a solution to this problem by adding the certificate to my java truststore under `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

What I still don't understand, is why this is necessary:

The specific website (https://api.ecs.echa.europa.eu) uses the root certificate *DigiCert Global Root CA*, which is already contained in the java truststore. Why is that not enough?

Sending requests to other websites that use this root certificate does work...

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Which version of Java?

Comment: If you're using an application container then adding to $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts won't help. you have to add it to the certs that the app container is using.

Comment: I'm using Java 13.0.1. Adding to cacerts does help but I want to know why it is necesarry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this error happens (probably) is because of a misconfigured server.
You can check here: https://whatsmychaincert.com/?api.ecs.echa.europa.eu

This site will tell you if your server cert chain is properly configured, which doesn't seem so.

Also, you are able generate the full cert chain on the same site using your public key.

Try to fix this and test again.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Unfortionally it's a server operated by an european authority so I can't do anything about it, but now I at least know where this (probably) comes from